# Could you tell me if this "proof" is correct?

Tags: calculus

I'll provide proof for L'Hôpital's Rule.

Let $h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$

$$ h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\frac{f(x)-f(a)+f(a)}{x-a}}{\frac{g(x)-g(a)+g(a)}{x-a}}\\
$$
$$
\lim_{x \to a}\frac{\frac{f(x)-f(a)+f(a)}{x-a}}{\frac{g(x)-g(a)+g(a)}{x-a}}
=\frac{f^{\prime}(x)+\frac{0}{x-a}}{g^{\prime}(x)+\frac{0}{x-a}}\\
$$

$$
\text{Since}\space f(a) = 0,\space g(a) = 0\\
$$

$$
\lim_{x \to a} h(x) = \frac{f^{\prime}(a)}{g^{\prime}(a)}
$$

Edit: Finally!

Comment: What I did was split the term so it would look like a derivative and also zero over whatever. We know that $f(a)=0$, regardless of the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In full, l'Hopital says that 
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}  $$
if the latter exists (and of course $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=0$). Your proof (if we correct a few typoes such as replace $f'(x)$ with  $f'(a)$ ) works only if $f(a),g(a)$ exist, $f'(a), g'(a)$ exist, $g'(a)\ne 0$.